# Can't declare gridview checkbox with checked in while loop using the SqlDataReader in a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, sqldatareader

Can't declare gridview checkbox with checked in while loop using the
`SqlDataReader` in a class?

```
protected void SelectedCourse()
{
    var courseid = lblCourseid.Text == "" ? 0 :Convert.ToInt64(lblCourseid.Text);
    var trimester = ddlTrimester.Text == "Select" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt64(ddlTrimester.Text);

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbFunctions.connection); 
    CheckBox cblCourseCode = (CheckBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("cblCourseCode");

    SqlCommand cmd = 
       new SqlCommand(@"SELECT 
                            COURSE_DIST.COURSECD, COURSE_DIST.COURSETITLE, 
                            COURSE_DIST.CREDIT, COURSE_DIST.COURSETP 
                        FROM 
                            COURSE_SELECTION 
                        INNER JOIN 
                            COURSE_DIST ON COURSE_SELECTION.COURSEID = COURSE_DIST.COURSEID 
                                        AND COURSE_SELECTION.TRIMESTER = COURSE_DIST.TRIMESTER 
                                        AND COURSE_SELECTION.COURSECD = COURSE_DIST.COURSECD 
                        WHERE 
                            COURSE_DIST.COURSEID = '" + courseid + "' 
                            AND COURSE_DIST.TRIMESTER = " + trimester + " 
                            AND COURSE_DIST.AYEAR = '" + ddlAcademicYear.Text + "' 
                            AND COURSE_DIST.SESSION = '" + ddlSession.Text + "'", con);

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read() == true)
    {
        var coursecd = dr["COURSECD"].ToString();
        cblCourseCode.Checked = coursecd;
        cblCourseCode.Checked = true;
    }

    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Actually this code is running perfectly, but my point is i can't declare/call "cblCourseCode" Checkbox here, because the Checkbox inside Gridview... Satinder singh

Comment: @marc_s......I got your point, but it's worked for me, only i can't call Gridview checkbox here, i mean can't Checked the checkbox. the only think i stuck here.